# Serialisation and Databasetechnics to locate objects

Tags: c++, database, sqlite, serialization, d

I was wondering if there is a (c++ or D) serialisation library that also provides technics to locate a certain object (which was saved to disk) based to certain criterias like a certain attribute combination.

I know about sqlite and mySQL and so own, but I search for an alternative.
Because those databases are not bound to a specific database schema,one known at compile time (of the library), they are only that good.
A library that knows the structures at compile time can be optimized to a very big degree for that structure. 
Maybe there is even a library creator, as input you give your c++ classes and desired location/identity attributes and as output you get a serialization/database-library that is heavily optimized for locating the objects based on your needs.

Additionally, I think sqlite and similar is overpowered for my use as I don’t need all the sql features, only the locating of an object based on its attributes..

Greetings,

--Marenz

Answer (score 2):

I have a work-in-progress [Serialization lib](http://www.dsource.org/projects/scrapple/browser/trunk/Serial) that I've been working on. (Some commentary [here](http://arrayboundserror.blogspot.com/search/label/serialization%20for%20D).) It's not done but it works, it just lacks a lot of polish and "convenience" features. If you are interested in using it, I'd be interested in feedback and feature requests.

As for DB storage, I'd just go with SQLite or MySQL. From what I've read, the query optimizers for DBs use *more* information than you can have a compile time (they look at data distributions and such).

OTOH I have been thinking of making a compile time SQL engine that uses meta-programming to build query plans at compile time. I've got a few other projects that I'll need to get done first though (like a `file_malloc` to allocate space in a file.)